# Upgrading to JWplayer 7.4.4

Tags: jwplayer7

I am upgrading jwplayer to 7.4.4 with hlshtml and default mode as html5 settings.
My player is working fine in firefox. But in chrome its giving error : cannot load m3u8 crossdomain access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Usually caused by a firewall blocking your access. On IE you can try: Go to "Internet Options" > "Secuirty" > "Internet" > choose "Custom Level" and scroll down to "Miscellaneous". One of the options should be "Access data sources across domain" - set this to "Enable".

If it is already enabled then it is likely that there is a firewall blocking you.

OR

When you get the error, do you have a shield on the right side of your address bar? You should be able to click on that and override the blocking for mixed content. Otherwise, you can force start the browser instance without the check through terminal, though, at that rate, would probably be easier to just use Safari until they get the cross-domain issue fixed.